# Error trying to execute react frontend (linked to backend)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, shell, deployment

I have recently tried to deploy a app consisting of react frontend and node backend on a linux machine.
While executing the frontend i got the following error:
(I used the command `npm start`)

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn xdg-open ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn xdg-open',
  path: 'xdg-open',
  spawnargs: [ 'http://localhost:3000' ]
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Comment: Does the machine have `xdg-open` installed? If you google "xdg-open ENOENT" you can find info about this, including command to install it

Comment: thx for your reply. fixed it already by reinstalling